# It is a type of Material

Tags: word

This compound word is a type of material

> It is formed of 2 words
>
> Both words are animals
>
> But the word itself has nothing to do with animals

It is useful.

May be more than one answer.

Comment: For clarity, is your word *AB* such that *A* and *B* are animals?

Comment: 'May be more than one answer' seems to be coming true here, and in some style... This is definitely starting to look too broad...

Comment: Correct @Ebe Isaac

Comment: If many answers could fit, then the puzzle is under-specified. A well-crafted puzzle will give enough information to rule in the intended solution while ruling out everything else. Potential solutions should be testable by referring to *the puzzle*, not by needing a response from the setter as to whether they're right or not. If the puzzle lacks enough specificity to make that determination, then it's probably *too broad*, and any "hints" added to fix that aren't really hints, they're a necessary part of the puzzle. This should be fixable with like one more criterion; I hope you add one!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What about

> SEALANT?

We use it in our homes

Answer (score 19):

A useful material which has nothing to do with animals is

> **[buckram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckram)** - a stiff cotton cloth, soaked in a sizing agent such as wheat starch and is used in bookbinding, curtain headings and hat making.

It is formed of 2 words, both words are animals

> **buck** - a male deer, antelope, sheep, goat, rabbit or hare & **ram** - a male sheep

... but another possibility is the very common word  ...

> carpet - **carp** the fish, overlapping with **pet** which may be various kinds of animals

Comment: Great @Tom. There is a much simpler answer too. Can you find it? You use it inside the house many times.

Answer (score 14):

It must be

> Tungsten, also known as **Wolfram**

Consisting of the animals

> Wolf and Ram

Commonly used in

> Lamps. It's the glowing wire

Comment: This has to be right

Answer (score 11):

An alternative, and obscure, answer (which I found programmatically) appears to be:

> **[Ravenduck](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q51954865)** (alt: Ravensduck; Raven's-duck)
>  A heavy sailcloth or canvas, made from cotton, hemp and flax.
>
>  ...yes, it is [obscure](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ravenduck&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cravenduck%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cravenduck%3B%2Cc0). Here is another [reference](http://languagehat.com/ravenduck/).

The components are:

> **[Raven](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/raven)**
>   Any of several, generally large and lustrous black species of birds in the genus Corvus.
>
>  **[Duck](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duck)**
>  An aquatic bird of the family Anatidae, having a flat bill and webbed feet.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's

> Duct tape. Pronounced, it can sound as duck and tape (worm). It's quite useful and it has nothing to do with animals.

Comment: In addition, there is a brand name that uses this pronounciation.

Comment: Surprisingly, that was the original name, referring to its water repellant properties; "duct tape" was a later development, even though it's seldom used in ductwork (at least not more than most places).  Now a company is marketing electrical tape as "duck tape."  English was a lot easier to understand before marketing.